# Finding the smallest $k$ such that $a^3+b^3+c^3+kabc\leq\frac16(k+3)(a^2(b+c)+b^2(a+c)+c^2(a+b))$, where $a,b,c$ are sides of a triangle

Tags: geometry, inequality, problem-solving

It is known that $a, b, c$ are the sides of the triangle. Determine the smallest value of $k$, so that
$$a^3+b^3+c^3+kabc\leq\frac {k+3}{6} (a^2(b+c)+b^2(a+c)+c^2(a+b))$$

My working:
$$a^3+b^3+c^3+kabc≤ \frac {k+3}{6} (a^2(b+c)+b^2(a+c)+c^2(a+b))$$
$$a^3+b^3+c^3+kabc≤ \frac {k+3}{6} (a^2b+a^2c+b^2a+b^2c+c^2a+c^2b)$$
$$a^3+b^3+c^3+kabc≤ \frac {k+3}{6} (a^2b+b^2a+a^2c+c^2a+b^2c+c^2b)$$
$$a^3+b^3+c^3+kabc≤ \frac {k+3}{6} (ab(a+b)+ac(a+c)+bc(b+c))$$

Can someone help me, I only process the data on the right side? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a%5E3%2Bb%5E3%2Bc%5E3%2Bkabc%5Cleq%5Cfrac%20%7Bk%2B3%7D%7B6%7D%20(a%5E2(b%2Bc)%2Bb%5E2(a%2Bc)%2Bc%5E2(a%2Bb))%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Atriangle%2C%20OR%20content%3Asmallest&p=1), the AoPS threads [inequality for triangle](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1442235p8216327) & [inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1133062p5274884), plus the AoPS message [Gerretsen inequality collect Post #$74$](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1281669p8217390), ...

Comment: (cont.) all indicate a value of $k = 9$. Also, [For $a$, $b$, $c$ the sides of a triangle, show $ 7(a+b+c)^3-9(a+b+c)\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)-108abc\ge0$](/q/3484343) has similar type terms to yours, but with coefficients that aren't compatible yours for any particular value of $k$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan The least value of $k$ is $9$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $a,b$ and $c$ are sides of a triangle, we are allowed to set $a=x+y$, $b=y+z$ and $c=x+z$. Now, let's define:
$$A=x^3+y^3+z^3 \\ B=x^2y+xy^2+z^2x+zx^2+y^2z+yz^2 \\C=xyz.$$

Note that by the Schur's inequality we already know that: $A+3C\ge B.$ Moreover it is not hard to see (by Muirhead's inequality) that $2A\ge B.$

Then, writing the inequality in terms of $A,B$ and $C$, we should have:
$$2A+3B+k(B+2C) \le \frac{k+3}{6} (2A+5B+12C). $$

By simplifying, we should have:

$$(\frac {k+3}{6})B\le (\frac {k-3}{3})A+6C.$$

If $k\ge 9$, then:

$$(\frac {k-3}{3})A+6C=2A+6C+(\frac{k-9}{3})A\ge 2B+ (\frac{k-9}{6})B=(\frac{k+3}{6})B.$$

Therefore the inequality holds if $k\ge9$.

---

Now, assume $k\lt 9$; then $\frac {k+3}{6} \gt \frac {k-3}{3}.$ Let's put $x=1, y=1, z=\epsilon$.

We should have:

$$(\frac{k+3}{6})(2+2\epsilon^2+2\epsilon)\le (\frac{k-3}{3})(2+\epsilon^3)+6\epsilon,$$
which is impossible for $\epsilon$ small enough.

Comment: You are right. Thank you!